# Take the name of certain columns to once cell for each row of the dataframe

Tags: r

So I have the following dataframe regarding the bus stop id and the buses lines that goes through that stop.

```
stop_id     20 goes    20 return    21 goes    21 return    22 goes    22 return 
C0001          X          NA          X           NA           X           NA
C0002          NA         X           NA          X            NA          X 
C0003          X          NA          NA          NA           X           NA 
C0004          NA         X           NA          NA           NA          X  
C0005          NA         NA          X           NA           X           NA 
C0006          NA         NA          NA          X            NA          X
```

If the line has an "X" instead of a NA, that means that that bus line passes through that stop, i.e. the lines 20 goes, 21 goes and 22 goes all pass through the C0001 stop.

What I need to do is to "summarise" all the columns that refer to the line into one new column called "lines". This column will have, for each bus stop, the bus lines that pass through it.

So what I´m looking for is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
stop_id    lines
C0001       20 goes - 21 goes - 22 goes
C0002       20 return - 21 return - 22 return
C0003       20 goes - 22 goes
C0004       20 return - 22 return
C0005       21 goes - 22 goes
C0006       21 return - 22 return
```

Further information: I need a generic way to do this, since my real data frame has 3709 bus stops and more than 90 lines.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or we can use `purrr::pmap`:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(lines = pmap_chr(df1[-1], ~ paste(names(df1)[-1][!is.na(c(...))],
                                            collapse = " - "))) %>%
  select(stop_id, lines)

  stop_id                             lines
1   C0001       20 goes - 21 goes - 22 goes
2   C0002 20 return - 21 return - 22 return
3   C0003                 20 goes - 22 goes
4   C0004             20 return - 22 return
5   C0005                 21 goes - 22 goes
6   C0006             21 return - 22 return
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way would be to loop over the rows and `paste` the column names of the non -NA elements

```
cbind(df1[1], lines = apply(df1[-1], 1, function(x) paste(names(x)[!is.na(x)],
          collapse = ' - ')))
```

-output

```
stop_id                             lines
1   C0001       20 goes - 21 goes - 22 goes
2   C0002 20 return - 21 return - 22 return
3   C0003                 20 goes - 22 goes
4   C0004             20 return - 22 return
5   C0005                 21 goes - 22 goes
6   C0006             21 return - 22 return
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(stop_id = c("C0001", "C0002", "C0003", "C0004", 
"C0005", "C0006"), `20 goes` = c("X", NA, "X", NA, NA, NA), `20 return` = c(NA, 
"X", NA, "X", NA, NA), `21 goes` = c("X", NA, NA, NA, "X", NA
), `21 return` = c(NA, "X", NA, NA, NA, "X"), `22 goes` = c("X", 
NA, "X", NA, "X", NA), `22 return` = c(NA, "X", NA, "X", NA, 
"X")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

We could also use `across` with `case_when` and `unite`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(`20 goes`:`22 return`, ~case_when(. == "X" ~ cur_column()), .names = 'new_{col}'), .keep="unused") %>%
  unite(New_Col, starts_with('new'), na.rm = TRUE, sep = ' - ')
```

Output:

```
 stop_id New_Col                          
  <chr>   <chr>                            
1 C0001   20 goes - 21 goes - 22 goes      
2 C0002   20 return - 21 return - 22 return
3 C0003   20 goes - 22 goes                
4 C0004   20 return - 22 return            
5 C0005   21 goes - 22 goes                
6 C0006   21 return - 22 return
```

Comment: I like this approach :=)

Answer (score 3):

A base R option using `aggregate` + `stack` (thank akrun's data)

```
aggregate(
    ind ~ stop_id,
    na.omit(cbind(df[1], stack(df[-1]))),
    paste0,
    collapse = "-"
)
```

gives

```
  stop_id                           ind
1   C0001       20 goes-21 goes-22 goes
2   C0002 20 return-21 return-22 return
3   C0003               20 goes-22 goes
4   C0004           20 return-22 return
5   C0005               21 goes-22 goes
6   C0006           21 return-22 return
```